# How can I set some value to inherited model class field in Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I made one model(ModelA) in which 2 choices present there, I am inheriting this model, in the other two models

```
CHOICES = (("work", "work"), ("Home", "Home"))
class ModelA(models.Model):
    type_of_address = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES)
    ...

class ForWorkModel(ModelA):
    type_of_address--->work

class ForHomeModel(ModelA):
    type_of_address--->Home
```

I want to inherit the model and want to set some field values, as I mentioned in the code.
Is there any way?

Comment: So you mean the *default* value? If not, why store it, and not return it as a static value?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom save on each of the individual models to set the desired string:

```
class ForWorkModel(ModelA):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # only change if the object is new
            self.type_of_address = "work"  # or CHOICES[0][0]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

or, I'm not 100% sure, but this might work:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

    type_of_address = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, default=cls.get_default_address)

class ForWorkModel(ModelA):
    def get_default_address():
        return "work"
```